# Magento 2 - How can I pull Category Names into Product Page and separate multiple Categories?

Tags: magento2, product-page

I want to pull category names into my title.phtml template. I am using the code below. It pulls in all categories. However, It does not put spaces in between the categories if the product is a part of more than one. How can I add spaces between categories here?

```
 <?php
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$product = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\Registry')->registry('current_product');
$categories = $product->getCategoryIds();
foreach($categories as $category){
    $cat = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Category')->load($category);
    echo $cat->getName();
    }


?>
```

Comment: could you share how you category is showing and how you want ?

Comment: As an example, if the product is in two categories it displays both categories but there is now spacing between the two.  If I had a category named shirts and a category named hats it shows up as "ShirtsHats" and not "Shirts Hats"

Comment: you can use echo "&nbsp;"; after category name!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the same code but by this way

```
 <?php
    $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
    $product = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\Registry')->registry('current_product');
    $categories = $product->getCategoryIds();
$category_names = "";
    foreach($categories as $category){
        $cat = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Category')->load($category);
        $category_names  .= $cat->getName()." | ";
    }

print trim($category_names, " | ");
    ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

the answer below is faster to render as the category collection is used. we should ideally use a function in a block or viewModel and use dependency injection instead of objectManager directly. Hopefully the below helps you going further

```
<?php
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$product = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\Registry')->registry('current_product');


/* @var \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Category\Collection $collection */
$collection = $objectManager->create(\Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Category\Collection::class);
$collection->addFieldToFilter('entity_id', $product->getCategoryIds());
$collection->addNameToResult();

$category_names = '';
foreach ($collection as $category) {
    $category_names  .= $category->getName();
}

print trim($category_names, " | ");
```